# IOS App is not shown in my account after successful upload from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa, application-loader

I am trying to upload my unity developed app on Apple store. Through Xcode my app uploaded successfully apload as shown in screen shot. But in my account it not shown. Suggest me any solution if there is any miss management/fault from my side

Comment: Check the email associated with your apple account, you might have received email regarding some issues while uploading the app.

Comment: Apple takes around one week time to check and verify your app. And if there is any issue than apple will mail you. and if verify successfully than your app will be on the app store.

Comment: You can check the current status in iTunes Connect.